# Does the sequence $(1,\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2^2},\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{3^2},\frac{1}{3^3},\ldots)$ converge?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> Does the sequence $(1,\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2^2},\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{3^2},\frac{1}{3^3}, \frac{1}{4}, \frac{1}{4^2},\frac{1}{4^3},\frac{1}{4^4},\ldots)$ converge?

The question is just that. This sequence can be seen as $p$-tails of sequences of the form $(\frac{1}{n^p})$ (where $p \in \mathbb{N}$) pasted together. As each of the sequences $(\frac{1}{n^p})$ converges to $0$, I'm quite tempted to think that this one does so too. Since $0$ is the only point it can converge to, it will be enough to prove that it's Cauchy. But so far I've been unable to do so. Thanks ahead.

Comment: Comparing with $(1,1/2,1/2,1/3,1/3,1/3,\ldots)$ may make things a bit more transparent.

Comment: Well, it's always greater than 0, but it is always less than or equal to $(1, 1/2, 1/2, 1/3, 1/3, 1/3, ...)$.

Comment: Whilst lyj's answer is absolutely complete, I do think this problem is almost tailor-made for understanding in terms of the limit superior and limit inferior of the sequence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any $\epsilon > 0,$ there exists $M > 0$ such that $\frac{1}{M} < \epsilon.$ In the sequence we are examining, there exists an index $N$ such that $a_N = \frac{1}{M},\, a_{N+1} = \frac{1}{M^2},$ etc. The point here is that for all $m, n \ge N,\,$ we have $a_m,\, a_n \le \frac{1}{M}.$ Hence, $|a_m - a_n| \le \frac{1}{M} < \epsilon,$ so the sequence is Cauchy.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** For $k\ge\frac{n^2-n+2}{2}$, $0<a_k\le\frac1n$.